# Common Search Functionality for Multiple UITableViews

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I want to implement a Common class which will handle the search functionality thus reusing it on UITableViews in multiple UIViewControllers. Is there any way to do this.
Currently i have created the static approach. Any directions for creating dynamic will be appreciated.

The Example i used is [this](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/) and [this](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-create-a-searchable-uitableview-in-ios-9/). I am using iOS 9. Xcode 7.3

Answer (score 0):

You can create one common class in which you have all search methods which are necessary (Search logic). 
ex.

```
- (NSArray*)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText AndFromSourceArray:(NSArray*)array
```

Implement sharedInstance of that class, so only first time instance will be created.

Now you have to call this search method which have been implemented in that class from

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
```

And you will get result array, that you can use it as data source for your tableview.

Comment: fine. I will try and let you know.